# Marking up or Modifying child nodes in XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, markup

I'm new to XSL, as will be obvious, and something very basic has stumped me. Let's say I have an XML document that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<essay><author>John Stamos</author>
<text>
    <p>In his song "Turn! Turn! Turn!," Bob Dylan quotes the Bible:
    <quotation>"To every thing there is a season, and a time to every purpose under the 
    heaven,"</quotation> which is a well-known quotation from Ecclesiastes.
    </p>
</text>
</essay>
```

For my current purposes, I want to mark up the text in the `<p>` element as well as the `<quotation>` element and print only these. IE, I want the output

```
    <span id="paragraph">In his song "Turn! Turn! Turn!," Bob Dylan quotes the Bible:
    <span id="quotation">"To every thing there is a season, and a time to every purpose under the 
    heaven,"</span> which is a well-known quotation from Ecclesiastes.</span>
```

When I use a stylesheet like the following, however, I run into trouble:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-    
c.org/ns/1.0"
version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//text"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <span id="paragraph"><xsl:value-of select="//p"/></span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="quotation">
    <span id="quotation"><xsl:value-of select="//quotation"/></span>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The quotation template never gets called; p, its parent, takes precedence apparently. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the **quotation** template never gets called is because you do not tell XSLT to continue processing within the template matching **p**. All your do is output an element, and so the XSLT processor will not continue doing any template matching for any descendants of the **p** element. What you need to do is add this line into the template (within the **span** element) so that XSLT can continue and match the **quotation** element.

```
<xsl:apply-templates />
```

In fact, you also have a problem with this line

```
<xsl:value-of select="//p"/>
```

This will actually return all the text under the first **p** element in document, not necessarily the one you are on. You could change it to this:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

But this will include any text within the nest **quotation** element. However, you don't actually need this **xsl:value-of** here at all in this case, because XSLT has the concept of built-in templates, which will output the text of any text nodes it finds, and so just doing **xsl:apply-templates** will handle this.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//text"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <span id="paragraph"><xsl:apply-templates /></span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="quotation">
    <span id="quotation"><xsl:apply-templates /></span>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response - that's really useful, answers my question, and works like a charm. I knew that the built-in behavior for templates is to output the contents of a node as text, but I (obviously, mistakenly) was under the impression that one a template was defined, it no longer had this behavior. If, e.g., the template `quotation` is defined, why does `apply-templates` use a built-in template to handle it? Or is it that the text is itself a child node?

Comment: The text within **quotation**, or any of your elements, are indeed separate nodes within the XML document, and not part of the element itself. Thus when you do **xsl:apply-templates**, it will be looking for templates that match these child nodes. You could do `<xsl:template match="quoatation/text()">` if you explicity wanted to process the text, but otherwise the built-in templates apply.

Comment: Thanks very much - that's really useful and explains everything.